# Providing multiple packages from a single source code

Tags: python, packaging, distutils

My package has a sub-package called `utils` which I want to be installable without the root package, so other projects can use it as well.

Is there any way to tell distutils that these are two packages (with the root one depending on `utils`) without splitting the source code into two repositories?

Comment: Just make it a new package? `my_project.utils` → ``my_project_utils``

Comment: As Kay said, make it a separate package and your current package can then reference it as a dependency.